# How should I JOIN my tables?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, join

I'm learning C# and some SQL server, and now i am trying to get information from my small database.

I have two tables: `Movie` and `MovieHandler`.

In the table Movie, i have `MovieCodeLable`, which is a uniqe number, and the `Title` of the movie.

In the MovieHandler table, i have `MovieCodeLable` which is the same as in my Movie table, and i have also her the colum `InStore`, which is eighter 0 or 1 for not in store or in store.

I'm trying to display the Title for the movies which is not in the store. But i find it hard figure out how to join tables.

I have tried this SQL query:

```
SELECT        Title
FROM          Movie
JOIN          MovieCodeLable
ON            MovieHandler.MovieCodeLable
WHERE         InStore = 0
```

Since i only get errors trying this query in Visual Studio 2012, i've probably missed something fundametal with SQL and JOINS, but i hope that someonw could make JOINS smooth as butter for me and others, struggeling to learn it.

Comment: Your `ON` condition is incomplete.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your JOIN is wrong and your ON clause is incomplete. The JOIN should involve the names of the 2 tables that you are joining, which in this case is Movie and MovieHandler The ON should be expression of format A = B. So your query should be:

```
SELECT        Title
FROM          Movie
JOIN          MovieHandler
ON            Movie.MovieCodeLable = MovieHandler.MovieCodeLable
WHERE         InStore = 0
```

Comment: Thank you for this fulfilling answer and solution for my problem, Thank you!

Comment: I'm just waiting for Stackoverflow to let me... :)

Comment: However, Visul Studio changed my query (Automatically) to an `INNER JOIN`.

Comment: INNER JOIN is a stricter version i.e. it will only retrieve those records which exist in both tables in the join for the matching field. I believe it's best practice to explicitly mention INNER JOIN, but I am not sure that's the only reason VS would do that.

Comment: Since there are many kinds of joins each with different behaviour, it is better to always explicitly state which is being used rather than trying to remember what is the default. IMHO a JOIN without specifying the kind of join should be treated as an error.

Comment: @CraigYoung Yes, that ought to be a best practice, at least when one is starting out with SQL.

Answer (score 2):

You need to specify both JOIN fields

```
SELECT        Title
FROM          Movie
JOIN          MovieHandler
ON            Movie.MovieCodeLable = MovieHandler.MovieCodeLable
WHERE         InStore = 0
```

Comment: Should have been MovieHandler ON, instead of MovieCodeLable ON, but otherwise it worked! Thank you.

Comment: The second table is called MovieHandler. This cannot work as MovieCodeLable is a field, not table.

Comment: Corrected it, I just copy-pasted yours, focusing on the `ON` part rather than on `JOIN` part.

Answer (score 1):

You have to do the query like this

```
SELECT        Title
FROM          Movie
JOIN          MovieHandler
ON            Movie.MovieCodeLable = MovieHandler.MovieCodeLable
WHERE         InStore = 0
```

You had to complete the ON condition.You need to specify the columns to match after ON condition.Go to this link there is explanations with tables http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp

Comment: there is no table named MovieCodeLable

Comment: Is it ok now @Mauricio

Answer (score 0):

I do it this way in oracle. Not sure if it will work for you...

Try:

```
Select Mv.Title 
      ,other_columns
  from Movie        Mv
      ,MovieHandler Mvh
 Where Mv.MovieCodeLable = Mvh.MovieCodeLable
   and (whatever other criteria you want
```

As long as MovieCodeLable is unique you're ok

Other_columns can be any column of either table  format with table.column syntax (I use table shortcuts Mv and Mvh to reference the tables, I don't know if this is legal for non-oracle)